# php imagick gif resize all frame

Tags: php, resize, gif, imagick

i have a problem to resize all frame using php imagick. it's take from official php doc example http://ir.php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php

```
/* Create a new imagick object and read in GIF */
$im = new Imagick("/tmp/bbb.gif");

/* Resize all frames */
foreach ($im as $frame) {
    /* 50x50 frames */
    $frame->thumbnailImage(50, 50);

    /* Set the virtual canvas to correct size */
    $frame->setImagePage(50, 50, 0, 0);
}

/* Notice writeImages instead of writeImage */
$im->writeImages("/tmp/zb.gif", true);
```

Comment: one frame gif generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the example on this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.coalesceimages.php

Depending on how the gif was created you may need the Coalesce; also not the coment about version problems.