# Imagick only giving single page for gif resize

Tags: php, gif, imagick

I've looked over different questions (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221927/php-imagick-gif-resize-all-frame) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361458/php-imagick-gif-animation-is-not-preserved)), and the [php documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361458/php-imagick-gif-animation-is-not-preserved). I've checked my Imagick version and the imagick::getVerison() function returns

```
{"versionNumber":1641,"versionString":"ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2014-03-06 Q16 http:\/\/www.imagemagick.org"}
```

So I am not using the bugged version (or at least I do not think I am) that is mentioned in the questions, and docs. I am using the following code to attempt to resize the gif.

```
public function resizeGif($path, $x, $y, $maintainRation = true) {
    $imageObject = new Imagick($path);

    $format = $imageObject->getImageFormat();
    if ($format != "GIF") {
        return false;
    }

    $imageObject = $imageObject->coalesceImages();

    $y = $this->getAspectRation($imageObject->getImageWidth(),
        $imageObject->getImageHeight(),
        $x);

    foreach ($imageObject as $frame) {
        $frame->thumbnailImage($x, $y);
        $frame->setImagePage($x, $y, 0, 0);
    }

    $newImageDir = 'img' . rand();
    $imageObject = $imageObject->deconstructImages(); 
    $imageObject->writeImages($newImageDir, true);

    $md5 = md5_file($newImageDir);

    return $md5;
}
```

But when I run the function, the gif is created and resized, but there is no animation. [this is the image I'm testing with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1NOC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me. It's possible you're using an older version of Imagick which has [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61879)

If so, you could either upgrade or work around it with:

```
file_put_contents('img' . rand().".gif", $imageObject->getImagesBlob());
```

btw the version 6.6.9-7 of ImageMagick will be 4 years old this April - it may be worth upgrading that as well.